# pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 2 parameter markers, but 34 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Tags: python, database, unit-testing, pytest, attributeerror

I have 2 errors to resolve.

1st error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 2 parameter markers, but 34 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

2nd error:

> AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'Exception'

I'm doing a unit test using pytest fixtures for database. I dont understand where do  I do the changes.

```
from database.db import DatabaseClient
from mykiosk_cl.kiosk_client import MyKiosk
import pytest
import pyodbc

@pytest.fixture
def setup_db():
    server = "sql-test-server-vdzbi.database.windows.net"
    database = "sql-test-database-vdzbi"
    username = "vdzbi-admin"
    password = "VD9ugvTf2"
    conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="+server+";DATABASE="+database+";UID="+username+";PWD="+password)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    return cursor


def test_freq_data(setup_db):
    cursor=setup_db
    db =DatabaseClient()
    mk = MyKiosk()
    get_data = mk.get_frequency_data()
    db.write_frequency_data(get_data)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM staging_db.Frequency")
    data =cursor.fetchall()
    assert data[0] == (0, 'einmalig'), "recheck"
    print("success")
```

These are the 2 errors in facing:

```
/tests/test_database.py::test_freq_data Failed: [undefined]AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'Exception'
self = <database.db.DatabaseClient object at 0x0000024A325FBF70>
data = [(0, 'einmalig'), (1, 'wöchentlich'), (2, '14-tägig'), (3, 'monatlich'), (4, '2-monatlich'), (5, 'quartalsweise'), ...]

    def write_frequency_data(self, data):
    
        stage_query = "INSERT INTO staging_db.Frequency (FreqId, Title) VALUES (?,?)"
        merge_query = """INSERT INTO mykiosk.Frequency(FreqId, Title)
            SELECT FreqId, Title
            FROM staging_db.Frequency stage
            WHERE stage.FreqId not in (Select FreqId from mykiosk.Frequency)"""
        truncate_query = "TRUNCATE TABLE staging_db.Frequency"
    
    
        try:
>           self.cursor.execute(stage_query,data)
E           pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 2 parameter markers, but 34 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

database\db.py:29: ProgrammingError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

setup_db = <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0000024A32230F30>

    def test_freq_data(setup_db):
        cursor=setup_db
        db =DatabaseClient()
        mk = MyKiosk()
        get_data = mk.get_frequency_data()
>       db.write_frequency_data(get_data)

tests\test_database.py:22: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <database.db.DatabaseClient object at 0x0000024A325FBF70>
data = [(0, 'einmalig'), (1, 'wöchentlich'), (2, '14-tägig'), (3, 'monatlich'), (4, '2-monatlich'), (5, 'quartalsweise'), ...]

    def write_frequency_data(self, data):
    
        stage_query = "INSERT INTO staging_db.Frequency (FreqId, Title) VALUES (?,?)"
        merge_query = """INSERT INTO mykiosk.Frequency(FreqId, Title)
            SELECT FreqId, Title
            FROM staging_db.Frequency stage
            WHERE stage.FreqId not in (Select FreqId from mykiosk.Frequency)"""
        truncate_query = "TRUNCATE TABLE staging_db.Frequency"
    
    
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(stage_query,data)
            self.cursor.execute(merge_query,data)
    
        except pyodbc.Error as e:
>           logger.Exception(e)
E           AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'Exception'
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: @KlausD. I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: `logger.exception` is written with a lower-case "e"

Comment: For the other question, we'll need to know what's in `data`; it looks like it has 34 items, but only 2 are wanted?

Comment: Ah, you've added it now; all good

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? My guess might be that some your data is of the datatype string and has an apostrophe or quotation - and you might have to escape that?

Answer (score 0):

- For the data, you probably want to insert it with a loop or with a bulk insert

  Loop:

  ```
  for row in data:
      self.cursor.execute(stage_query, row)
  ```

  Bulk insert:

  ```
  self.cursor.executemany(stage_query, data)
  ```
- For the other problem, `logger.exception(...)` is written with a lower-case "e"

Comment: thanks for the 2nd solution. 1st one again throwing error:         try:
>           self.cursor.executemany(stage_query,data)
E           AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Connection' object has no attribute 'executemany'

Comment: I would like to use executemany and not the loop. But the error is ocuurring

Comment: Somehow you got the connection in the cursor variable? Check to see where you're setting it and make sure the names all match up?

Comment: The [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide may help...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Still faces issues. I'll look into the debug link. Thanks again.